# Is it OK to be able to paste text in a password box?

Tags: user-interface, passwords

What do you web developers think? Should we disable pasting in masked password boxes in our web applications or not. Could this be a security hole or cause confusion or unwanted results? This is probably a question about user experience and not so much about programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pasting is OK, in IMHO, and is expected. *Copying*, however, is usually forbidden, with good reason. That is expected now, too. You really just want to go with what most users are familiar with unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: Yikes my grammar is bad today!

Answer (score 14):

Pasting is **perfectly OK** actually disabling sometimes can cause bigger issues. Most of the users use keepass or similar applications to store strong passwords.

If **you force people to type every time this can force them to choose weaker passwords.**

Comment: For the anecdote, sometime I find sites limiting password length ("Only 6 chars or less") and even kind ("Only alphanumeric chars"). In general, they are the same...

Comment: oh yeah hate that as well, that's so much worse than this though.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't disable pasting.

Some secure password management applications include support for putting their stored passwords directly into the C&P buffer without ever showing it on screen, and disabling paste would make those applications less useful.

Answer (score 1):

Allow pasting, but make sure the user notes that whatever he pasted did not fit the max length. I am using KeePass that autogenerates 10 character passwords for me, it's a mess when my password wont work because the registration only used the first 8 chars, or similar.

Also make sure that the login password boxes have the same max length as the registration password boxes.

Answer (score 0):

No, I would not. I frequently paste passwords such as randomly generated ones for resets. I do not think it would be a security risk for the Web application, only that the risk would be inherited by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting can only be bad if it causes your database query to fail. Outside of that, everyone else has sane reasons for allowing it. Remote Desktop pisses me off when I can't paste a password because I use KeePass to manage complex passwords. What I'm left doing is leaving the password in plain text on the screen while I type it.